# jQuery window view load animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Got a lazyload style script I'm working on whereby a function gets called when the user comes into view (its graphs raising from the ground). problem I'm having is that the graphs tend to be constantly changing their height (50.04012040% etc). I also have other divs that are shown once this height reaches it's data-attr.

**JS:**

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var total = 100;

  if( ! /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

            // Quote Form x-slide in
        if(wScroll > $('#statistics').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.7)) {

            // Animated graph
            $(function() {
                $("#bars li .bar").each( function( key, bar ) {
                    var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

                    $(this).animate({
                        'height' : percentage + '%'
                    }, 1000);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});

$(".stat-button").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseover(function () {
            console.log('hover');
                    $(this).siblings(".stat").fadeIn('1000');
        }).mouseout(function () {
                    $(this).siblings(".stat").fadeOut('1500');
        });
    });
```

problem is that the stat buttons can't come into view until the percentage has been met, but if this is constantly change it never will.

Fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/no0mvffz/

Comment: without the whole code of yours: js+css+html it's impossible to see what's the problem. i reproduced your js http://jsfiddle.net/no0mvffz/ it works just fine.

Comment: Have updated the fiddle to include html,css etc. http://jsfiddle.net/no0mvffz/2/ none of the hover buttons show after the animation. The buttons should appear after the graph has finished its animation.

Comment: you don't have any stopper condition when changing a bar height, scrolling seems to trigger every time you go up and down. I assume it's enough for the bars to grow once on first load. let's add a condition to check if they their height is zero, and only then grow http://jsfiddle.net/no0mvffz/4/